# Can I find out whether a host function was overwritten?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to check whether a browser-provided function has been replaced by user code?

```
function alert(str){
    document.write(str);
}

alert('hello world');
```

Comment: no. It's not possible to check whether a host object is overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to know if browser methods are overwirtten or not. e.g.

```
function foo(){
  return 'foo was called';
}

foo.toString = function() {
                 return 'function alert() {\n    [garbage code]\n}';
               };
var a = window.alert;
window.alert = foo; 

a(window.alert);  
document.write(alert);
```

About all you can say is that if you don't get the default response, the method was probably modified since the *toString* method of host methods is generally read only. But if you get the default, you don't know if it was modified or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can check

```
if (/function alert\(\) \{\s*\[native code\]\s*\}/.test(alert))
```

The regex is necessary because Firefox returns newlines.

Note that this can be easily defeated by overwriting `alert.toString` or `Function.prototype.toString`.

Comment: Completely unreliable since the *toString* method is not guaranteed to be read only. Anyone messing with a host method can modify its `toString` method to return any value they want, including the default (which I don't think is standardised anywhere).